# How to make an object adapt to another size when the app runs in another device. (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, layout

I'm  new to programmimg and Swift. And I want to know how to make an object adapts it's size if I run the app in a different device.

For example,

I have a view that I setup like this:

**var myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, 165)**

I want it to have 165 of height in iPhone 6 and 6s, but what should I do if I want it to have, for example, 100 in iPhone 5?

Thanks so much. I know this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't create the view programmatically, you should use the story board. Create a UIview and give it the constraints that you want, with these constraints it auto-sizes to all iPhone devices. This makes it easier for you! Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone not preferring story board and like programmatically doing everthing, try:

`CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)`